# taking string with spaces does not work in my function

Tags: c, string

I want to my function take input string with any spaces. But my taking input line is not working somehow and prints `1` without taking my input. I even tried `fgets` and `gets` function to avoid this but result is the same. Can anyone help me? Line 16 is taking input part.

```
double setup_tree(char object[20], char parentobject[20]) {
    double total;
    int i;
    double val;
    char input[100];
    char answer[101];
    char names[20][20];
    int numcounts[20];
    int objectnumber;
    if (parentobject[0] == ' ') {
        printf("Define %s\n", object);   
    } else {
        printf("Define %s in %s\n", object, parentobject);    
    }
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", input); 
    printf("1");
    remove_more_than_one_space(answer, input);
    objectnumber = define_typeof_description(answer);
    if (objectnumber == 0) {
        //printf("0lalol ");
        sscanf(answer, "%lf", total);
        return total;
    }
    total = 0;
    parse_the_answer(answer, names, numcounts, objectnumber);
    printf("1lalol");
    for (i = 0; i < objectnumber; i++) {
        val = setup_tree(names[i], object);
        total += (numcounts[i]) * val;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post your sample input file in a separate code block

Comment: I didn't take input from file and I cannot enter the input. That's the problem.

Comment: Did you read any input before calling this function? The problem may be that it didn't read a full line, so this is reading the rest of that line.

Comment: If you want to read a line at a time, it's best to use `fgets()` rather than `scanf()`.

Comment: Yes, I read input in main function.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: If you want to use the whole line as input I suggest to use `fgets` (and remove the newline if present) instead of `scanf`.

Comment: @KaanUslu A [mre] in your case might be a `main` function that contains all your input and output in the same sequence as in your real program without unrelated processing functions and with the input you used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your posted code is calling three separate functions that you're _not_ showing. _If_ you're _only_ getting `1` as output, probably (e.g.) `remove_more_than_one_space` is [silently] aborting, possibly due to UB or a segfault. We'll need to see these other functions.

Comment: @KaanUslu Anyway, showing  a [mre], as already requested in comments, would allow us to give an explanation of your original problem. If you mix `scanf` and `fgets` you may also get problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem most probably comes from `scanf()` reading a pending newline left in `stdin` by a previous call to `scanf()`.

You can avoid this with `scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", input);`

Also note that you should protect against invalid input with `scanf(" %99[^\n]%*c", input);`